# Ansible prompt "No existing session" in manual executing the playbook

Tags: session, ssh, ansible, key, version

Current situation:

I can ssh to SwitchA with ssh client.

With the same playbook, it can ssh to the SwitchA by cronjob, but I can't execute the playbook manually and got the below error message.

How can I solve this issue and make it successful in executing this playbook manually?

```
ansible-playbook -i SwitchA.yml playbook.yml
```

**Ansible debugging**

```
<172.26.192.229> connection transport is cli
<172.26.192.229> using connection plugin network_cli (was local)
<172.26.192.229> starting connection from persistent connection plugin
<172.26.192.229> local domain socket does not exist, starting it
<172.26.192.229> control socket path is /home/xxxx/.ansible/pc/67b0b2e86d
<172.26.192.229> loaded cliconf plugin for network_os ce
<172.26.192.229> 
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/paramiko_ssh.py", line 352, in _connect_uncached
    **ssh_connect_kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 412, in connect
    server_key = t.get_remote_server_key()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 834, in get_remote_server_key
    raise SSHException("No existing session")
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No existing session

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ansible-connection", line 104, in start
    self.connection._connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/network_cli.py", line 327, in _connect
    ssh = self.paramiko_conn._connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/paramiko_ssh.py", line 245, in _connect
    self.ssh = SSH_CONNECTION_CACHE[cache_key] = self._connect_uncached()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/paramiko_ssh.py", line 368, in _connect_uncached
    raise AnsibleConnectionFailure(msg)
ansible.errors.AnsibleConnectionFailure: No existing session

fatal: [SwitchA]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "No existing session"
}
```

I found there a difference
**Cronjob**

```json
        "ansible_playbook_python": "/usr/bin/python2", 
        "ansible_python_interpreter": "python3", 
        "ansible_version": {
            "full": "2.9.27", 
            "major": 2, 
            "minor": 9, 
            "revision": 27, 
            "string": "2.9.27"
        }
```

**Manual Execution**

```json
                "ansible_python_interpreter": "python3",
                "ansible_version": {
                    "full": "2.8.1",
                    "major": 2,
                    "minor": 8,
                    "revision": 1,
                    "string": "2.8.1"
                }
```

My Playbook

```yaml
  connection: local
  serial: 30
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    cli:
      host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
      port: 22
      username: "{{ username }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
      transport: cli

    - name: "Testing"
      ce_command:
        commands: "{{ command_list }}"
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
        timeout: 900
      register: MyResult
```

SwitchA debug:

```
SSH/7/RECV_PKT:Received ssh2 msg kex init packet.
SSH/7/KEX_DERECTION:Kex for direction is in.
SSH/7/CHOOSE_ENCRYPT:Chose encryption algorithm:aes128-ctr.
SSH/7/CHOOSE_MAC:Chose MAC algorithm:hmac-sha2-256.
SSH/7/KEX_DERECTION:Kex for direction is out.
SSH/7/CHOOSE_ENCRYPT:Chose encryption algorithm:aes128-ctr.
SSH/7/CHOOSE_MAC:Chose MAC algorithm:hmac-sha2-256.
SSH/7/CHOOSE_KEX:Choose Kex algorithm:diffie-hellman-group16-sha512.
SSH/7/KEX_UNSUPPORT:Unsupported Kex algorithm:ecdsa-sha2-nistp256!
SSH/7/FSM_MOVE:FSM moved from SSH_Sub1_KEX_Init to SSH_Sub1_KEX_GRP_Init.
SSH/7/RECV_PKT:Received ssh2 msg kexdh init packet.
SSH/7/FSM_MOVE:FSM moved from SSH_Sub1_KEX_GRP_Init to SSH_Sub1_KEX_GRP_Reply.
SSH/7/no_info:Begin to compute the dh shared key.
SSH/7/no_info:The line phylink is null. ulLineIndex = 6
SSH/7/no_info:Fail to inform to dh key result. ulRet = 0x1
```

Comment: I think indeed you need to look into differences between Python/Ansible differences by looking the user under which you run your cron vs. user that you use for manual execution and any environment variable that you source for cron (probably you don't source any)

Comment: Could you fix your playbook example to make it valid? It looks like you didn't paste the `hosts:`,  `tasks:`, and probably some oher keywords.

Comment: Also, have you tried to 1) use `network_cli` connection as recommended in the [`ce_command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/network/ce_command_module.html#notes) module documentation? 2) Update your Ansible version? 2.9 maintenance ended years ago, maybe it has some issues affecting you.